# influxdb insert error: type float, already exists as type integer dropped=1

Tags: influxdb

some measurement fields only appear with values greater than 0 very rarely, we need to make sure  to insert a float value the very first time in order to ensure influxdb will allocate that field as float. Because if we are not careful with the cast, things like this can happen:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./src/[REDACTED]", line 301, in <module>
    insert(test.results, test.results)
  File "./src/[REDACTED]", line 193, in upload
    ret = creds.write_points([{"measurement": "networks",
  File "/usr/local/src/[REDACTED]/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 603, in write_points
    return self._write_points(points=points,
  File "/usr/local/src/[REDACTED]/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 681, in _write_points
    self.write(
  File "/usr/local/src/[REDACTED]/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 413, in write
    self.request(
  File "/usr/local/src/[REDACTED]/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 378, in request
    raise InfluxDBClientError(err_msg, response.status_code)
influxdb.exceptions.InfluxDBClientError: 400: {"error":"partial write: field type conflict: input field \"example_field\" on measurement \"[REDACTED]\" is type float, already exists as type integer dropped=1"}
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in the influxdb 1.8 [docs](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/troubleshooting/frequently-asked-questions/#can-i-change-a-field-s-data-type), changing a field type is complicated.
A ridiculously simple solution is to just change its name after deploying the code with the appropriate cast `example_field2 = float(example_field)`, so now example_field (int) and  example_field2 (float) may coexist (maybe up until the current shard lives?), and example_field2 should carry the float typed data.